# Does running the ESP8266 or any other MCU below the minimum voltage cause damage?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, nodemcu

I'm powering an ESP8266 MCU from a 2.5V voltage source that occasionally drops to 2V when a motor runs (runs for about 5 seconds twice a day). The battery is low. Incidentally, the MCU is powering a FET which turns the motor on and off.

The [ESP8266 datasheet](https://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) specifies a voltage range of 2.5V ~ 3.6V, but what if the voltage drops below? Does it cause damage to the MCU?

Side note: I'm also driving a couple of low voltage LEDs, and they tend to flicker when the motor is running, and on the scope shows a noisy signal, so I'm thinking a cap near the MCU/LEDs would help with that.

[image: Voltage drop at MCU VIN]

(1: VIN, 2: FET gate)

Comment: Probably not, but this is a serious design flaw and LEDs flickering is EMC failure waiting to happen. Show schematic!

Comment: Damage, probably no. But you should use the motor with a diode (or LDO) and a super-capacitor for its own supply ... and good decoupling capacitor for ESP8266.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCU would just fail to operate properly when it has less voltage than it needs to work properly.

So the MCU itself would likely be fine.

There are many other scenarios that may be problematic though.

The MCU may have a reset circuitry that can detect undervoltage, and reset the MCU, before the voltage is too low to execute program correctly. If not, then the MCU might run at undervoltage some time before it is reset. During this time, the operations it performs are unknown, and it might execute code to erase it's memory or anything you can think of.
It is also possible the MCU just hangs without reset and keeps the motor on until batteries run out.

In this case, it might be that at some point the voltage at FET gate is not enough to keep the FET fully turned on, so the FET on resistance gets higher and it may heat up from the power it needs to dissipate.

So it's not so much about the MCU what happens to it, but what the whole system does when voltage gets too low and MCU may or may not be running properly.

Comment: "It is also possible the MCU just hangs without reset and keeps the motor on until batteries run out." -- Yes, I've seen this, actually on my current design at very low voltage. Manual reset brings it back to life, but that requires you to be at the device.

Comment: In a poor design, low voltage for extended periods can allow inadvertant writes to non-volatile memory, corrupting it. The only issue that I have personally seen.